# How can I Track Changes of a 'Change Case' operation?

Tags: microsoft-word

In MS Word 2010, with Track Changes enabled, if I re-type a phrase such as "the quick brown fox" to "The Quick Brown Fox" by selecting and overwriting the first letter of each word it generates eight separate changes (four word deletions and four word insertions).

If I select the whole phrase and use the Change Case operation (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>7</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>) it capitalises each word as I desire but does not create any tracked change.

Is there a way to enable change-tracking of the latter operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Word/microsoft.public.word.application.errors/2006-10/msg00386.html), some argue it's a feature. I'd call it a bug.

> When you use "Change Case" you are making a formatting change rather than an editing change. Since an actual edit is not being made it's not viewed as an Insertion or Deletion, which is what most primarily view as a tracked change. While most formatting changes are tracked, such as bold, font, etc, changing the case is not tracked as a formatting change.

Solution/workaround was found in same link:

> [If] this is something you must track then what I suggest is for you to use Tools/Compare and Merge documents instead. Save a copy of the original document and make your modifications (without using Tracked Changes) in the copy. Then when you want to view the revisions, open the copy of the document and go to Tools/Compare and Merge Documents, navigate to the original document and turn on the "Legal blackline" option.
>
> Like using Track Changes, all differences between the documents will be displayed as revisions and the changes you made using Format/Change. Case will be identified as well.

Comment: That link is a relevant discussion. However, Track Changes is capable of tracking other `Formatting Change`s such as `Left Align` and `Font Size 9pt` etc. Is there some fundamental distinction between a `Formatting Change` and this `formatting change`?